# Как связать radiobutton с select?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, radio

Как сделать так, чтоб при выборе в radio какого-то значение, то select переключался на это же значение?

```
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
<select>

<input name="select" type="radio">1
<input name="select" type="radio">2
<input name="select" type="radio">3
<input name="select" type="radio">4
<input name="select" type="radio">5
```

Comment: Вообще правильный ответ на этот вопрос: использовать для этого нормальную библиотеку с binding'ами. К примеру, angular, react, knockout и т.д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант без jQuery с использованием индексов вместо `value`:

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="select"]');

for (const i in inputs) {
  if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
      select.selectedIndex = i;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<select>
<br>
<input name="select" type="radio">1
<input name="select" type="radio">2
<input name="select" type="radio">3
<input name="select" type="radio">4
<input name="select" type="radio">5
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6p2kkLp/)

Answer (score 4):

Нужно добавить в оба тега атрибуты `value`, после чего на основании значения этого атрибута у `input` выбирать соответствующее значение у `select`, по событию `change`, которое будет слушаться у `input`.

```js
$("input[name=select]").on("change", function(){
$("select").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<select>
<br>
<input name="select" type="radio" value="1">1<br>
<input name="select" type="radio" value="2">2<br>
<input name="select" type="radio" value="3">3<br>
<input name="select" type="radio" value="4">4<br>
<input name="select" type="radio" value="5">5
```